# How to programmatically delete all the contents within a folder with in Cloud storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a folder called "myfolder" within Cloud storage bucket. It has files like a.log, b.log etc. How can I programmatically delete all these files from the folder in the bucket.

I want some some java example code to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I framed this sample by taking snippets from our production code base. Please note the usage of `setPrefix(folder)` to filter contents from a bucket.

So the logic is get all contents from the bucket and filter based on folder name, the delete it.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.*;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;

import com.google.api.services.storage.Storage;
import com.google.api.services.storage.model.*;

public void deleteFolder(String bucketName, String folder) throws IOException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    GoogleCredential.Builder credentialBuilder = new GoogleCredential.Builder();
    final GoogleCredential credential = credentialBuilder
            .setTransport(httpTransport).setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountId("YourServiceAccountId")
            // .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("PrivateKeyFile"))
            .build();
    Storage storage = new Storage(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
        new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request)
                    throws IOException {
                credential.initialize(request);
            }
        });
    // PLEASE NOTE THE USAGE OF setPrefix(folder) TO FILTER ITEMS IN FOLDER
    Objects objectsInFolder = storage.objects().list(bucketName).setPrefix(folder).execute();
    for(StorageObject object : objectsInFolder.getItems()) {
        storage.objects().delete(bucketName, object.getName()).execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm doing something like this, and I'm finding it very slow to delete a directory with thousands of objects. Is there really no way to delete a folder or at least do a batch delete?

Comment: Also, you may want to wrap the for-loop in a while loop because the api only gives you 1000 objects at a time.